# getElementById but for placeholder?

Tags: javascript, html

I´m trying to automate the filling of some information in a webpage with javascript.

All the fields have IDs, for example:

```
<div id="cc-container" class="field has-float-label">
     <input placeholder="ccnumber" id="credit_card_number" maxlength="16" name="credit_card[ovv]" size="16" type="tel" value="">
</div>
```

And then I just insert the info with:

```
document.getElementById("credit_card_number").focus();
document.getElementById("credit_card_number").value = variable_ccnumber;
```

But the last one doesn´t have an ID:

```
<div id="cvv-container" class="visa has-float-label">
     <input placeholder="cvv" maxlength="4" name="credit_card[meknk]" size="4" type="tel" value="">
</div>
```

How can I insert what I want in this case?

Thanks.

PD: I'm only starting to code so please don´t assume I will understand everything you throw at me

Comment: try this `getElementsByName`

Comment: Name/Class/querySelector

Comment: @xmaster document.getElementByName("credit_card[meknk]").focus();
document.getElementById("credit_card[meknk]").value = variable_ccnumber;   Like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which allows any ***valid CSS*** as selector with *name* attribute:

```js
document.querySelector('[name="credit_card[meknk]"]').value = 'variable_ccnumber';
```

```html
<div id="cvv-container" class="visa has-float-label">
  <input placeholder="cvv" maxlength="4" name="credit_card[meknk]" size="4" type="tel" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: How can I contact you?